# My custom JQuery code is causing IE7 to run very slow but not other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, sharepoint-2010, pagespeed

This is my first ever question on this site so I apologise in advance if anything sounds a little inexperienced regarding the rules (I have quickly read them though.)

Anyway on to my problem.

I have built a custom menu in SharePoint 2010 which uses UL's and is customised via CSS and some JQuery.

It looks exactly how I want it to and performs great in IE8, FF & Chrome. I have tested it on a old slow machine we have here and it works fine.

The issue arises when I test this on a machine which has IE7 installed. For some reason when hovering over the top menu items it's runs extreemly slowly.

I am only just beginning to learn JQuery (in the last week) so I expect I have done something completely wrong with my code.

It is slowed by the following code:

```
$("ul.SIDGlobalNav li:not(ul.SIDGlobalNav li ul li)").mouseenter(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':not(.LISIDCurrentSelected, .SIDCurrentSelectedParent)'))
  {
    $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected div, UL.SIDGlobalNav  SIDCurrentSelectedParent div").css('backgroundPosition', 'left top');
    $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected div a, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent div a").css('backgroundPosition', 'right top').addClass('tabdown');
    if ($(this).children('ul').length < 1)
    {
      $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected ul, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent  ul").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } 
  }
})
```

I will explain why the code is there so that it helps you understand my thinking a little more.

The menu is a tabs style menu with a dropline. When a tab from the menu or one of it's children is selected the tab is raised and the menu items on the dropline are visible.

When a user hovers over another menu tab I have set the JQuery to drop the current selected tab and hide the dropbar.

I can provide images if this helps at all?

Any pointer on why it might be happening is much appriciated.

Thank you in advance.

Rich

Answer (score 2):

IE6 and IE7 have very bad JavaScript performance overall; IE8 is (2x) better, but still far behind the competition. IE9(beta) should have as good or better JavaScript performance as the competition.

An additional problem is that IE (<= 8 anyway) does not have a `getElementsByClassName` method. So JQuery has to do all the work when you give it a class based CSS-selector, and it cannot rely on a (quick) native browser function.

Try to evaluate the node selectors as few times as possible; if you can cache the `'UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent'` result set, and do subselections on it, it should run a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for this - It makes sense that they perform better and it seems to show this. I have heard of caching but I don't know JQuery/Javascript. I will go away and try and find out how this is done now and do what you have suggested above.

Comment: I have also just discovered that the CPU process for IE fly's up while I am waiting for it to render. Just reading a blog about caching and performance now.

Answer (score 0):

IE has been known to have severe caching issues with sprites.  When this slowdown issue occurs, inspect the number of HTTP requests that are being issued by your browser.  It *could* be the case that you're firing off a lot of requests to get images each time that jquery runs.

If that's not the case, I can help you dive into some performance optimizations to get your JavaScript runtime expenses down.

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy response - I am going to look into the http requests and see if this helps.

Comment: Np, and it seems like the other people on this thread are right on the money as far as the JavaScript optimizations available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$("ul.SIDGlobalNav > li:not(.LISIDCurrentSelected, .SIDCurrentSelectedParent)").mouseenter(function(){
    $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected div, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent div").css('backgroundPosition', 'left top');
    $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected div a, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent div a").css('backgroundPosition', 'right top').addClass('tabdown');

    if ($(this).children('ul').length < 1)
    {
        $("UL.SIDGlobalNav .LISIDCurrentSelected ul, UL.SIDGlobalNav .SIDCurrentSelectedParent  ul").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

I have changed the first select so it doesn't look in to the sub `ul`, which negates the need of the first if statement.

Comment: Thanks for this - I gave it a go and it's still the same. It might be worth me noting that the loading of the page is a normal speed it's only taking ages to respond as soon as the mouse hovers over the tab. I have counted about 10 seconds on average.